# Case Statement in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I was trying to use case statement in the select statement like this in SQL server 2005 and i get the error "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."  Cant a Case be used inside SQL query?!

```
declare @TypeofDayID int
set @TypeofDayID = (Select TypeofDayID from RepInfo where RepInfoID = @RepInfoID)


Select CASE 
    WHEN @TypeofDayID = 1 
        THEN (Select * from RepInfo RD inner join SellingInfo S on S.RepInfoID = @RepInfoID)
    WHEN @TypeofDayID = 2
        THEN (Select * from RepInfo RD inner join UpgradingInfo U on U.RepInfoID = @RepDailyID)
    WHEN @TypeofDayID = 9 or @TypeofDayID = 10
        THEN (Select * from RepInfo RD inner join DeliveryInfo D on D.RepDailyID = @RepDailyID)
    END
from RepInfo RD
```

Comment: When you use a `CASE` statement on your `SELECT` is to define a single column, you can't do `SELECT CASE WHEN something THEN SELECT *...`

Comment: No. A subquery can't. Use `if` blocks.

Comment: Agreed with above. You can use CASE to test values during your SELECT, but if you are looking to execute different kinds of code, then you will need to use IF instead.

Comment: You may experience performance problems with this query or the current answers as well, because one of the 3 conditionals may be optimized for and the other two may be slower, or the query plan will be rebuilt often. http://stackoverflow.com/q/289625/16391

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CASE` isn't used for logical flow control... use `IF` / `ELSE IF` instead:

```
declare @TypeofDayID int
set @TypeofDayID = (Select TypeofDayID from RepInfo where RepInfoID = @RepInfoID)

IF @TypeofDayID = 1 
  Select * 
  from RepInfo RD inner join SellingInfo S on S.RepInfoID = @RepInfoID
ELSE IF @TypeofDayID = 2
  Select * 
  from RepInfo RD inner join UpgradingInfo U on U.RepInfoID = @RepDailyID
ELSE IF @TypeofDayID = 9 or @TypeofDayID = 10
  Select * 
  from RepInfo RD inner join DeliveryInfo D on D.RepDailyID = @RepDailyID
```

Keep in mind... since you're using `SELECT *`, and joining to a different table based on `@TypeOfDayID`, you'll likely end up with a jagged result set, meaning that you'll have a varying number of columns based on which branch is taken.

This can be a pain to work with programmatically, so it would be a good idea to avoid `SELECT *` for this reason, as well as other reasons...

Comment: Not only the SELECT *, but it also runs the chance of poor performance with those conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do can be better handled this way.

```
declare @TypeofDayID int
set @TypeofDayID = (Select TypeofDayID from RepInfo where RepInfoID = @RepInfoID)

IF @TypeofDayID = 1 
    Select * 
    from RepInfo RD 
    inner join SellingInfo S on S.RepInfoID = @RepInfoID
ELSE IF @TypeofDayID = 2
    Select * 
    from RepInfo RD 
    inner join UpgradingInfo U on U.RepInfoID = @RepDailyID
ELSE IF @TypeofDayID = 9 or @TypeofDayID = 10
    Select * 
    from RepInfo RD 
    inner join DeliveryInfo D on D.RepDailyID = @RepDailyID
```